# iOS push notification action when device is locked

Tags: ios, push-notification

I'm handling push notifications in my app. In the push notification alert, I've "Cancel" and "Join" buttons. When the app is in background and not locked, the alert shows well with cancel and join buttons. When join is clicked, app will send a request to web server that user joined. This is working fine.

But when the phone is locked, I'm seeing notification without any buttons. When user unlocks the device, which action will be sent to the app: cancel or join?

How should I handle the situation where "join" is sent but the user wants to cancel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot specify more than one action for a push notification. In other words, if the user taps the Cancel button, the OS will not even launch your app. Similarly, when the user unlocks the device by swiping over the notification, they implicitly execute the push notification's action button.

In short: your app is never launched unless the user invokes the notification's action.

The question is whether interpreting that single action as "Join" is a good idea. (I think it isn't. Your app should ask for confirmation.)

Comment: Thanks Ole, So, I should handle this "Join" in applicationDidFinishLoading as well as applicationDidReceiveRemoteNotification. Isn't it?